# Regular expression in Drools

Tags: java, regex, drools

I keep getting compile errors when I try to write my rules.

I am trying to translate this condition into drools

```
if(model.type.series != null && model.type.series.name.mathes(".*FANR.*") || 
                      model.type.series.name.matches(".*SANA.*"))
    //do something....
```

This is what I have...

```
rule "Rule 01" salience 0    
    when
            m : model(type.series != null, 
                      type.series.name.matches(".*FANR.*") || 
                      type.series.name.matches(".*SANA.*") 
            a : Result(state == Result.GOOD )   
    then
        a.setState(RESULT.BAD);
          ....
end
```

What I was trying to do is to use regular expression to match the part of the string where the 'name' is String type. As I am fair new to drools I don't see where it can cause problems, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correct Drools syntax, according to the `matches` operator, as described in the Drools manual.

```
rule FANRorSANA
when
    $n: model($v: type.series.name matches ".*(FANR|SANA).*")
then
```

And you can use the power of regular expressions for testing alternatives.